# Change button size runtime using Qt

Tags: qt

I have created a QLineEdit and few QPushButtons in the mainwindow ui and I set there size to (100,100).

If I resize the the window I would like to reize the buttons and a text box at runtime.

Comment: If you are not using [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) you should start now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

**For Example look this :**

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget;
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");

QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(window);
layout->addWidget(button1, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(button2, 0, 1);
layout->addWidget(button3, 1, 0, 1, 2);
layout->addWidget(button4, 2, 0);
layout->addWidget(button5, 2, 1);

window->show();
```